# How do I get ZipArchive.CreateEntry name encoding right?

Tags: c#, encoding, zip

I use the following code to create a zip archive with C#.

```
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
{
    var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(name + ".pdf");
    ...
}
```

The name often consist of Swedish characters such as ÅÄÖ åäö. When I open the zip and look at the names the Swedish chars are garbled like this "Fl+Âdesm+ñtare.pdf".

I tried fixing the name encoding with this code. But it didn't work.

```
var iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
var utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(name);
var isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
var isoName = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out DotNetZip library (get it via NuGet). Here is a code sample, where i use cp866 encoding:

```
private string GenerateZipFile(string filename, BetPool betPool)
    {
        using (var zip = new ZipFile(Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866")))
        {
            //zip.Password = AppConfigHelper.Key + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("ddMMyy");                
            zip.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866");
            zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
            zip.AddFile(filename, "");
            var zipFilename = FormZipFileName(betPool);
            zip.Save(zipFilename);
            return zipFilename;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it impossible to solve with the System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive?

Comment: @AdrianRosca i couldn't find a fix, gave up and used 3rd-party library

Comment: Got it to work with your code example. The Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866") in the ZipFile constructor wasn't needed. The AlternateEncoding and the AlternateEncodingUsage did the trick.

Comment: While it may be useful side-information, this does not actually answer the asked question, which is for ZipArchive.CreateEntry API.

Answer (score 4):

Since DotNetZip is a dead project and this article is relevant to google searches, here is an alternative solution with the IO.Compression library :

```
Archive = New IO.Compression.ZipArchive(Stream, ZipArchiveMode, LeaveOpen, Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage))
```

This might not cover all conversions, from what I gathered from the sources on the subject, the underlying code uses the local machine's (server) regional culture's encoding page for entry names. Mapping them with that encoding explicitly has fixed the issue for my client-domain, no guarantees that it's a silver bullet however.

Answer (score 0):

using (var zip = new ZipArchive(ZipFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Read, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866")))

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @Taslim Oseni Why is this not an answer? Based on his answer and your comment I cannot conclude anything. Is it a non-answer because it does not work? Is it because you think it requires explanation? I have no idea.